# Nodemon is restarting on page reload

Tags: node.js, nodemon, boilerplate

I have simple hackathon nodejs boilerplate i changed few things actually.
I installed nodemon and plugin to watch scss. I start both scss plugin and nodemon but everytime i reload page(f5) or write url it restart(due to change). It restarts even when i disable scss plugin.
Problem began after i started using my own nodemon.json file

```
{
    "ext": "css,js"
}
```

when i remove that file everything is allright.

Any idea what i can do?
This is boilerplate i am using https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter

Comment: are you trying to restart only when css/js change or only when non-css/js change?

Comment: Only when CSS or js change

Comment: if you have the scss plugin watching for style changes, you shouldn't have nodemon watching those and restarting the server with each change. the server should ship the latest for whatever is at that (example: public/css/mystlyles.css) path

Comment: But when i have nodemon only for js. And sass watcher is turned on it restarts server only when js changes and css wont change(file changes) but website looks the same and i need to restart it. But know i am wondering that this boilerplate is saving public wonder in pc for some time that is the problem probably :D omg i am idiot. Thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude extensions (which I believe you want to exclude .scss and .css since those would be updated by the sass watcher), you can do an exclude in your nodemon.json

```
{
  "ignore": ["*.css", "*.css.map", "*.scss"],
  "ext": "js"
}
```

This should work since the css path shouldn't change in any way (the location / names of the scss/css files will be the same) so any time code goes to look for them, they will get the latest version.

If you are using the starter, you might want to consider ignoring the public directory all together since the latest version will always be shipped by the backend:

```
{
  "ignore": ["public*"]
}
```